# L.control.IconLayers error when you used in react

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

When we use `leaflet_iconlayers` in react, we get the following error. I want to use this plugin which is a control in the leaflet in react.

Error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): leaflet__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.Control.IconLayers is not a constructor.
```

I have installed

`npm I leaflet_iconlayers`

Comment: please add the related codes.

Comment: suppose you have got a react leaflt map and you would like to add leaflet-Iconlayers on it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article [ask] about how to asking questions also read this article [mre] about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement. Good luck 

Comment: this is my code  https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-euclid-cnqo7?file=/src/App.js:0-2094

Comment: leaflet-iconlayers plugin is not working in react.

Comment: https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/877

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: No, I am using jsx

Comment: I want to add iconlayers leaflet to my project react. I have already installed npm install leafle-iconlayers in my project but unfortunately that is not added to the project.

Comment: is anybody solve my problem.?